# Price increase when product synchronize on eBay?

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, m2e

Our site is in Magento 2.
We sell our products on Amazon & eBay. We integrate M2 extension for it.
But we want to increase product price on eBay by 10%, when we synchronize product on eBay.
Any one help me for how to set it.

Comment: Can you explain more ? You may use screen shots as well if u are comfortable.

Comment: Our site is in magento 2.
We integrate M2E prevention for sell our product on eBay.
In magento we have one product; which price is 100 rupees.
But we want to sell this product on eBay in 110 rupees.
If any setting in admin side or in M2E extension which auto increase price when we synchronize this product in eBay.
Else any coding which give this functionality for increase price 10%.

Comment: I think you understand now; what we want.

Comment: If it works for you please mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

RTFM :P

Please check your sales policies where you definde you price fields. There should be a modifier that let you adjust prices by totals or percents ...

Check https://docs.m2epro.com/display/eBayMagento2/Price,+Quantity+and+Format+Policy#Price,QuantityandFormatPolicy-Price

Comment: It's working fine as per our requirement.Thank you so much for help.